# Where does OpenCV keep the cascades on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

For some reason, I can't find the data directory from OpenCV which stores all the cascades as XML files... I've installed OpenCV from homebrew and I want to try it out with the premade classifiers before I train my own.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for by `grep`-ing through the homebrew Cellar.
This was the command that helped me `grep -r cascade /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/`

And this is the result I was looking for in the results.
`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.1/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml`